# Get variables from one php script to another

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-activity

I have three activities in android studio!The first holds the password and email EditTexts,the second holds a button 'pause'.The third activity holds a text.
How to get the values of email and password when I click the button pause on second screen using php script?I am using a MYSQL database and a table inside of this database with email,password and pause.

Comment: Does the android app get results from the php file?add the code from the three activities and the php file?

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: You asked this before. You should explain better what you want as i dont understand anything of this. For instance why would you need a php script to transfer variables from one activity to the other? Makes no sense. Well explain please.

Comment: I just need to know in php we use sessions to use a variable in different scripts,but because android studio does not support session global variables I can not call the email and password in the third screen.Using post it does not work?

Comment: `android studio does not support session global variables`. ?? Android Studio? What a nonsense. Your app is communicating with a php server maybe. Not Android Studio. You talk unclear. Your problems are unclear.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are looking for passing data from one activity to another. You can do that like below

```
Intent foo = new Intent(currentActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
foo.putExtra("Email", mail);
startActivity(foo);
```

If you want to save on a database you can use **[volley package](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)** for GET and POST data from and to a server.
I hope you are looking for the first one.